Why does my GitHub linting action fail when using Python 3.12.3 with an Astroid building error?
After changing from Python 3.10.0 to 3.12.3 our workflow fails with:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/bin/pylint", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 25, in run_pylint
    PylintRun(argv or sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylint/lint/run.py", line 207, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 650, in check
    check_parallel(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pylint/lint/parallel.py", line 152, in check_parallel
    for (
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 873, in next
    raise value
astroid.exceptions.AstroidBuildingError: Building error when trying to create ast representation of module 'program_name.core.startup_rest'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Workflow
name: linting
on: [push]
jobs:
  linting-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python 3.12.3
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.12.3'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
      - name: ansible_lint
        run: ansible-lint resources/playbook/roles/program_name/tasks/main.yaml
      - name: pylint_lint
        run: pylint program_name

in the pylint_lint step. I am unsure what causes this. One source suggested to add __init__.py to all folders which I have now added, but this didn't fix the issue.
The pylint version set by the requirements-dev.txt is pylint==2.14.5
Additional Information
In the past we used Python 3.10.0 for our linting, which worked fine, but that caused issues when we switched to Python 3.12.03 in our working environment. Python 3.12.03 apparently knows more pylint errors. Disabling some of those at certain places (aka pylint: disable=...) raises an error on workflow execution with Python 3.10.0, because it doesn't know them.

So is bibigrid.core.startup_rest one of your own modules?

What is the version of pylint that gets installed (I can see requirements-dev.txt, but not the contents; presumably that contains pylint and possibly a version restriction).

@9769953 yes. I missed that one and have replaced it with program_name instead to avoid confusion. Thank you for pointing it out.
I will add the pylint version to the question. (pylint==2.14.5)

Is there any possibility you can upgrade your Pylint? The current version appears to be 3.3.1, which also brings a new Astroid version (which is a dependency of Pylint), and this combination of newer packages may already have solved this error.

Pylint 2.14.5 is not supported for Python 3.12; it's only supported for Python versions 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. It has not been tested with 3.12: it may work, it may fail (and the latter seems to be the case).
So you should upgrade your Pylint version to a Python 3.12 compatible version (pip --upgrade pylint should do that for you).
In fact, when you upgrade Python by a minor or major version (not so much a bugfix release), you should upgrade all your packages to match the new version: you can't rely on previously installed packages to be forward-compatible with newer Python versions (these packages could never even have been tested against that newer Python version).

Thank you. I then assume that Pycharm ignored the pip package and used its own pylint version in the plugin? That would explain why pylint ran without issue there.

@Natan Possibly. I'm not familiar enough with PyCharm and its setup to know about that. But, it should somewhere have a path set to the Python interpreter, and possibly also to Pylint. Which are perhaps independently configured. Or alternatively, your local (PyCharm) environment was upgraded manually, but the files for the package (used by the CI; I assume you're using a CI tool to run Pylint and tests remotely) were not updated (I've done that: manually upgraded things, forgetting to update the package in requirements-dev.txt, then found out thanks to the CI results; which is what it's for).

This is a bug in astroid, you do not give the pylint/astroid version so:

First try to upgrade to see if it's fixed in the latest pylint version (currently ">=3.3")
Then try to compare the dependencies locally and in CI (pip freeze on both sides), it's frequent to have a local install with "old packages" that match the project requirements but then one of your dependency release a new package and that one get fetched in the CI. If this is a dependency issue you can set the dependency to what you have locally as a temp fix.
Then open an issue in pylint-dev/astroid, if you can reproduce the issue so it can be fixed in pylint/astroid)


When your GitHub Linting Action fails with an Astroid building error while using Python 3.10.0, it is likely due to compatibility issues between the version of Astroid (or one of its dependencies) and Python 3.10.

I made a mistake in the title. It's an issue with 3.12.3. However, pylint works on my local machine with python 3.12.3 so I am unsure what causes the issue.
